# Is Firstrade a legitimately free broker?

Tags: investing, online-brokerage, robinhood

I'm curious about Firstrade.  I know RobinHood is also fee-free, but some users claim that they make money but frontrunning, which can be costly in the long run. Curious to know if Firstrade is legitimately free.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the legitimacy of Firstrade.  But if you believe that  selling order flow to high-frequency firms (Payment For Order Flow) is front running then Robinhood is guilty as charged.

RH denies this in their FAQs list but it's clearly spelled out in their quarterly financial statement. It's about $2.50 per $10,000. PFOF can result in inferior trade fills for an investor.